# Angular2/Typescript - default query string parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that checks for the existence of parameters inside a query string and acts accordingly. However, when I attempt to transpile the code I get errors such as

error TS2339: Property 'oauth_token' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: any; }'

My component reads as follows

```
constructor ( 
    private router: Router
) {}

ngOnInit() {

    if ( this.router.routerState.snapshot.queryParams.hasOwnProperty('oauth_token') ) {
... do stuff here ...

    }
}
```

Can anybody please advise on how to default query string parameters?

Comment: I don't think that hadOwnProperty is right way to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `[]` operator to access the properties:

```
const oauthToken = this.router.routerState.snapshot.queryParams['oauth_token'];
if (oauthToken) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks very much. My learning curve is obviously huge.